# Accessing a corrupted shared library

Tags: assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit

Here is the code of `cpuid2.s`:

```
#cpuid2.s view the cpuid vendor id string using c library calls
.section .data
output:
    .asciz "The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"

.section .bss
    .lcomm buffer, 12

.section .text
.global _start
_start:
    movl $0, %eax
    cpuid
    movl $buffer, %edi
    movl %ebx, (%edi)
    movl %edx, 4(%edi)
    movl %ecx, 8(%edi)
    push $buffer
    push $output
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp
    push $0
    call exit
```

I assemble, link, and run it as so:

```
as -o cpuid2.o cpuid2.s
ld -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o cpuid2 -lc cpuid2.o
./cpuid2
bash: ./cpuid2: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

I've searched StackOverflow for this error. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541955/gnu-assembler-accessing-a-corrupted-shared-library-error) which is similar to mine. And I tried the method given by @rasion. Like this:

```
as -32 -o cpuid2.o cpuid2.s
ld -melf_i386 -L/lib -lc -o cpuid2 cpuid2.o
ld: cannot find -lc
```

His answer doesn't solve my problem. I hope someone can help me.

I'm using AT&T syntax with GNU assembler.

My computer has 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've sort of realized, you're trying to compile assembly for a 32 bit machine, on a 64 bit machine. With the commands you copied and pasted, you're letting `as` and `ld` know that you're compiling something 32 bit.

The issue you've run into is that you don't have a 32 bit version of libc available to link against.

```
apt-get install libc6:i386 libc6-dev-i386
```

Then assemble the code with:

```
as --32 -o cpuid2.o cpuid2.s
```

and finally link it with:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o cpuid2 -lc cpuid2.o
```

Then it should work:

```
[jkominek@kyatt /tmp]$ ./cpuid2 
The processor Vendor ID is 'GenuineIntel'
```

Comment: @zhengzhiliu Sorry, try installing libc6-dev-i386 too. I managed to omit it from the question initially. (It's included above, now.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use libc, you should use entry point `main` not `_start`. Make sure you have `gcc-multilib` installed, and simply use gcc to compile and link: `gcc -o cpuid2 cpuid2.s`. That should automatically do all the right things for you.