# "Accessing a corrupted shared library"

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, ld, glibc

I'm trying to dynamically link a 64-bit `nasm` program using `ld` instead of `gcc`, in a 64-bit Linux system. The assembly code is this:

```
extern printf
extern exit

section .data
  msg: db "Hello x%d", 10, 0   

section .text
global _start

_start:
  mov rdi, [rel msg]
  mov rsi, 64
  call printf

  mov rdi, 0
  call exit
```

I'm trying to call `printf` and `exit` from `libc`. I assemble and build with:

```
$ nasm -felf64 src/printf.asm -o bin/printf.o
$ ld bin/printf.o -lc -I /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o bin/printf
```

Then I run and get an error:

```
$ bin/printf
bash: bin/printf: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

There is a question with a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419857/accessing-a-corrupted-shared-library), but the problem there is the opposite: they try to create a 32-bit program in a 64-bit machine. I'm just trying to make a 64-bit program.

---

I found the solution: there is a /lib64 directory with a ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 that you should use to link with 64-bit libraries. I'm still getting a segmentation fault though.

Comment: You can always ask GCC to tell you what it uses as options to pass to the linker. This answer tells you how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1170843/3857942

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm just trying to make a 64-bit program.

Yes, but you are supplying 32-bit interpreter for it, which wouldn't work for a 64-bit program.

Try using `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` instead.

After that fix, the program starts, but crashes with `SIGSEGV` inside `printf`. Fix:

```
mov rdi, [rel msg]
```

should be:

```
mov rdi, msg
```

Comment: I think he was going for lea rdi, [rel msg] which would also be the preferred PIC method